# Primefaces 6.1 + HTTPS = Erro no IE11

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, internet-explorer, https

Coloquei um projeto **JSF** com **primefaces** parar rodar com **https** e quando entramos no **IE11** uma surpresa: não funciona!

Dispara um erro de navegador assim:

> CSS3111: @font-face Detected an unknown error. File:
>   SohoGothicPro-Light.woff

Com **http** funciona tudo uma maravilha, como **SSL** no **IE** não.
Alguém ai já passou por isso? Alguma ideia de como resolver?

Comment: Creio que no HTTPS o "fallback" não esteja sendo carregado, pode também ser um problema com CORS. Tem como fornecer detalhes?

Comment: Não tem segredo. Desenvolvemos o produto sem problemas. Quando coloquei em produção com proxy reverso fazendo SSL, no IE11 não funciona. Já tentei abrir o CORS 100% e continuou com o mesmo erro

Comment: Abrir o CORS? Fala ajustar os headers? Se for isto ok, me diga fora este erro, aparece outros erros no console quando em HTTPS?

Comment: Isso mesmo. NO site da microsoft fala o seguinte: "Foi encontrado um problema desconhecido com os "Web Open Font Format (WOFF)", e "fonte Embedded OpenType (EOT)" da fonte das Folhas de Estilo em Cascata (CSS)."

Comment: Ninguem do forum oficial me responde. Testei versão prime 5 até a 6.1. Todas geram esse erro.

Comment: Quanto roda o projeto sem SSL. Tudo funciona 100%. O problema é HTTPS.

Comment: Sim, foi exatamente isto que eu disse, um problema no fallback (se é que tem fallback para a fonte), supondo que a fonte de fallback não tenha carregado então ele acaba carregando a outra fonte, esse erro na verdade é bastante ambiguo, não tem como saber, eu só estou supondo que seja problema ao carregar a fonte de fallback para IE, por isso que perguntei se tem outros erros, não deve ser no WOFF deve ser no fallback.

Comment: Aparece somente esse erro. Não tem outros!

Comment: Posta a parte do CSS que tem as fontes, é quase certeza que seja um problema com fallback, também pode ser um problema no cache e talvez o erro esteja ocorrendo *"sem SSL"*, mas o cache esteja "te enganando", como eu disse o problema é ambiguo, sem detalhes não tem como responder.

Comment: Não tem CSS. O erro acontece dentro do arquivo.woff. Quando eu abro ele, só tem caracter zuado.

Comment: O que é esse fallback?

Comment: Provavelmente **não é** dentro da fonte Fernanado, o erro pode ser dentro do woff, mas entenda que para IE ele vai usar outra coisa que não o woff, chamamos de fallback, uma funcionalidade ou recurso alternativo, ou fonte alternativa, no proprio `@font` vc configura multiplas fontes, a que carregar será usada se não funciona é carregada outra, no caso quando vc usa o SSL o IE não esta reconhecendo o fallback (provavelmente fonte alternativa) e acaba tentando carregar a fonte woff, então por favor poste o CSS, pois o erro é ambiguo (pode ser qualquer coisa) como eu já disse.

Comment: Resumindo vc pode estar correto, mas esse erro claramente só poderá ser determinado com o minimo de código para analisarmos e termos certeza se é no SSL. Precisamos de detalhes, erros ambiguos não tem como ser determinados, sempre forneça detalhes.

Comment: Primefaces gera um css enorme. Vou postar aqui?

Comment: Posta a parte relevante do CSS, como eu já citei antes, a parte aonde tem `@font`, só selecionar e copiar, se tiver um link online da página manda também

Comment: @font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url("/ib2/javax.faces.resource/fa/fontawesome-webfont.eot.faces?ln=primefaces&v=6.1?v=4.7.0");src:url("/ib2/javax.faces.resource/fa/fontawesome-webfont.eot.faces?ln=primefaces&v=6.1&#iefix&v=4.7.0") format('embedded-opentype'),url("/ib2/javax.faces.resource/fa/fontawesome-webfont.woff2.faces?ln=primefaces&v=6.1?v=4.7.0") format('woff2'),url("/ib2/javax.faces.resource/fa/fontawesome-webfont.woff.faces?ln=primefaces&v=6.1?v=4.7.0") format('woff'),url("/ib2/javax.faces.resource/fa/fontawesome-webfont.ttf.faces?ln=primefaces&v=6.1?v=4.7.0") format('truetype

Comment: Esse é o começo...

Comment: Edita a pergunta Fernando, não poste no comentário.